# Echo value from only assigned array value

Tags: php, mysql

Please check following codes and tell me how can i echo $error[] array when each error receives a value when my code conditions meet. or is there any short solution for that? i want to echo error message when conditions meet. whats the best short hand solution for that?

```
if (isset($_POST['submit_update'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['old_pass']) || empty($_POST['new_pass'])) {
        $error[] = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Error: Field can not be empty</div>';
    }elseif ($user->check_old_admin_pass($_POST['old_pass'])==true) {
        if($user->update_pass($_POST['new_pass'])==true){
            $error[] = '<div class="alert alert-success">Success: New password is set</div>';
        }else{
            $error[] = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Error: Fail to update</div>';
        }
    }else{
        $error[] = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Error: Wrong old password</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Put it in a simple variable (not array). Or you can display "all" of them (now only 1), when you would like multiple messages then your code is ready

Comment: it's just html. build a string instead, or `echo implode('', $error)`

Comment: `$errorString .= Error1; $errorString .= Error2`

Answer (score 0):

You could just try something very simple like so:

```
<?php

    $strError    = '';
    if(isset($error) && !empty($error)){
        $strError .= '<div class="error_wrapper">';
        $strError .= implode("\n", $errors);
        $strError .= '</div>';
    }
    echo $strError;
```